# I would like to set AnimatedOpacity to only a part, but it will only be reflected in the terminal child widget

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, animation, user-experience

I want to create a button that displays a border while being pressed.
However, I want to control whether the border is shown or hidden using `AnimatedOpacity`, but the button itself becomes hidden.
How can I make the button itself visible all the time, but only the border can be controlled by `AnimatedOpacity`?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class AppAnimatedButton extends HookWidget {
  const AppAnimatedButton({
    required double borderRadius,
    required Future<void> Function() onTap,
    bool? isSecondFlameBorder,
    super.key,
  })  : _borderRadius = borderRadius,
        _isSecondFlameBorder = isSecondFlameBorder ?? false,
        _onTap = onTap;

  final bool _isSecondFlameBorder;
  final double _borderRadius;
  final Future<void> Function() _onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isTapDowning = useState(false);
    const radius = 10.0;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTapCancel: () => isTapDowning.value = false,
      onTapDown: (_) => isTapDowning.value = true,
      onTapUp: (_) async {
        isTapDowning.value = false;
        _onTap();
      },
      child: AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: isTapDowning.value ? 1 : 0,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: _isSecondFlameBorder && isTapDowning.value
                  ? Colors.blue
                  : Colors.transparent,
              width: 4,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_borderRadius * 1.55),
          ),
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For reference, I wanted to create an animation like this for the Amazon app.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `AnimatedOpacity` widget that is wrapping the first `Container`, and change that `Container` to `AnimatedContainer`. Use the same `curve` and `duration` that was on the `AnimatedOpacity` before to the `AnimatedContainer`.

```dart
return GestureDetector(
  // ...
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      // ...
    ),
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      // ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
However, when it comes to AnimatedContainer animations, there are some gray moments. I don't want to change the border color.

Comment: Replace `Colors.transparent` with `Colors.blue.withOpacity(0)`. That should fix it

Comment: I did as you said and it was done. thank you! ! !